# Leaflet support for larger click radius with CircleMarker

Tags: click, leaflet

Does Leaflet support a method for allowing the CircleMarker created to be of, say, radius 5, but allow the radius from the lat/lng of the marker that is sensitive to click events (shows a bound popup) to be, say, 15?

I currently create a second, larger circle with opacity 0 to achieve this, but would like a "cleaner" solution should it exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't have a click tolerance option like you're looking for. It uses DOM elements for markers, and regular event handling to capture click events.

Your approach of adding a transparent circle or border is a reasonable one, and the one I would likely use if I were in your position. Just keep in mind that at higher zoom levels, 10 extra pixels around a marker is significant, and might confuse users with unexpected behavior if the markers are close or overlapping.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case. Double circles is the solution I implemented - just not ideal when either zoomed in as you mentioned or when hundreds of markers are on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Since Leaflet [version 1.3.0](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-2018-01-15), a [`tolerance`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#renderer-tolerance)
may be specified to the [`Renderer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#canvas). This property defines "how much to extend click tolerance round a path/object on the map":

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    renderer: L.canvas({ tolerance: 15 })
});
```